# How to add multiple labels using for loop In an applet?

Tags: java

I want to add 70 labels and 70 checkboxes in an applet I takes lot of code when we write normally . how to add  these labels using for loop

Comment: create the elements in for loop and attach to the panel.Is this really difficult?

Comment: you need to make a array of labels

Comment: Please show an attemp or specify what you specifically don't understand about adding components to a panel using a loop. As this question current stands, it lacks effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a for loop to add Labels to an array. Something like

```
List<Label> li = new List<Label>();
for(int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
{
   li.add(new Label("label " + i));
}
```

If you don't want to use an array just you could just add the labels directly to your layout.

```
FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
for(int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
{
   fl.add(new Label("label " + i));
}
```